# FullInformationOutputRegulator returns InverseMatrix badly conditioned error

Tags: matrix, control-systems

I have the following linear system:

```
    lintest={{{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-3.73609*10^6, -1182.17, 
   733736., -9833.62, 1.71254*10^6, 
   15815.6, -8.85737*10^7, -855045., -5.18821*10^8, -4.86313*10^6, 
   410405., 39814.4}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {-1683.19, -5.22481, -14113.7, -225.71, 220396., 2017.11, 
   3.80543*10^6, 36186.2, 2.38147*10^7, 
   221393., -8547.37, -1676.25}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {174.74, 0.144667, 0, 0, -14853.2, -320.813, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 246.9, 0.45, 0, 
   0, -13506.7, -304.986, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -14436.5, -315.76, 0, -1.}, {0, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {194.591, 0.171368, 3186.36, 
   9.58711, 14088.8, 128.941, 245839., 2337.98, 1.5377*10^6, 
   14296.1, -556.787, -108.306}}, {{0}, {239.374}, {0}, \
{-0.00203788}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {-0.00534967}}, {{0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0}}, {{0}, {0}}}

FullInformationOutputRegulator[StateSpaceModel[lintest], {{-36.56159791301381`, 
   6.208102739888733`, -211.87164443617408`, -5.007094837581512`, 
   1316.6702867366175`, 
   14.086691788609967`, -152.03642568191782`, -78.41260924183058`, 
   2738.5351201449253`, -417.28163428048873`, -38.645006974271176`, \
-15.662761066993506`}}]
```

The error I receive is:

```
 Inverse::luc: Result for Inverse of badly conditioned matrix {{-0.00239637,-0.00471432,-0.00656976,-0.0127072,-0.0258032,-0.0272771,-0.063539,0.189724,0.15842,-0.0706669,-0.000759485,-0.000365158},{<<1>>},<<8>>,{<<1>>},{-0.000151048,0.000702333,<<8>>,-0.000118767,-0.0000392698}} may contain significant numerical errors.
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: I would like to avoid this error. Is it possible in some way to ask Mathematica to chop[] down its matrix inversion? @corey979

Comment: Isn't that already a pretty explicit warning? The matrix involved is badly conditioned (I get $2.56\times10^{10}$), so you stand to lose a lot of significant figures in your results if you use it. If you have an exact version of that matrix, consider using it instead.

Comment: If I Invert[] the matrix and multiply it by the matrix itself, I find a messy IdentityMatrix that can be cleaned up by using Chop[]. I believe I can't do much about the matrix as it is obtained numerically. @J.M.

Comment: That test you did really doesn't count for much in numerics. (You're multiplying one badly conditioned matrix with another, after all.) Again, it's a warning that your system is inherently ill-conditioned. Either come up with a way to get an exact matrix, or switch to a different model that does not generate badly-conditioned matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could try to workaround the problem of encountering an ill-conditioned matrix.

As suggested, work with exact values.

```
With[{dn = 0}, 
FullInformationOutputRegulator[Rationalize[lintest, dn], 
Rationalize[{-36.56159791301381`, 
 6.208102739888733`, -211.87164443617408`, -5.007094837581512`, 
 1316.6702867366175`, 
 14.086691788609967`, -152.03642568191782`, -78.41260924183058`, 
 2738.5351201449253`, -417.28163428048873`, -38.645006974271176`, \
-15.662761066993506`}, dn]] // N]
```

> {{57857.6, -27.2618, 1.33232*10^6, 7618.43, 6.60134*10^6, 102382., 
>     9.80951*10^7, 
>     1.55658*10^6, -2.20907*10^9, -4.13939*10^7, -68709.1, -180109.}}

Or, try to pass an equivalent state-space model

```
StateSpaceModel@TransferFunctionModel@lintest
Last@ControllableDecomposition@lintest
Last@ObservableDecomposition@lintest
```

Here the number of states are different and the poles that need to be specified will also change.

Comment: Thanks Suba! You made my day again!! I tried rationalizing but stupidly rationalized only 'lintest'!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to provide the extra jab.